# Does the Windows Logo exist as an Icon?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

In a Windows PC, the Windows Logo is shown on the start menu button. Does this logo exist in a DLL or an EXE as an ICO (icon file) anywhere in Windows 7?

Interestingly, I have found the Windows 10 (or 8) Logo in explorer.exe. I have found an icon depicting the Taskbar and Start menu together, which includes the Windows 7 logo (another similar one contained an older one, likely Windows 95).

But is there a Windows logo that exists as a standalone icon anywhere in any EXE or DLL or any other icon library?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you are asking if the windows 10 logo exists in windows 7? Because the chances are that it doesn't, simply because Microsoft changed the logo AFTER windows 7 came out. It might be shipped with other newer software such as Office, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @LPChip No, I found the Win10 logo in Win7. I want to find the Win7 logo in Win7.

Comment: Basically, my question is "What is the source of the Windows 7 Start Menu icon (the Windows 7 logo)?"

Comment: Well, the source is a .png image, not an Icon. There probably is an icon somewhere, but I haven't found it. Maybe there's something similar in shell32.dll or progman.exe?

Comment: @LPChip do you know where the .png is?

Comment: Mostlikely embedded in explorer.exe as resource. There's a windows program that I think is called resedit or reshack that is a resource editor/hacker which allows you to edit/change embedded files in exe and dll files.

Comment: @LPChip I use Greenfish Editor Pro to view those. (it is a really good image editor) I had looked in there earlier and found the Windows 10 logo. I just noticed that their is something like a sprite that has what I was looking for. Don't know why I didn't notice it before. There are like 12 of these and are all Bitmaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Logo as seen in Windows 7 on the Start Menu button is found as a Bitmap image sprite in explorer.exe ("C:\Windows\explorer.exe"). There are 12 versions of it, and as far as I can tell there are actually only 4 variations, each being a different size. If you use a program such as Greenfish Icon Editor Pro or Resource Hacker, you can extract it and (depending on the program used) you can crop the image you want and convert it into an ICO (icon file).

For the actual Windows logo, see the following EXE's or DLL's:

- Windows 10 logo in Windows 7: C:\Windows\explorer.exe

  - Contains both Blue and White versions.
- Windows 7 logo in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\winver.exe
- Black Windows 7 logo in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\Display.dll
- Windows XP in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\slui.exe
- Windows 95 in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\comptsui.dll

  - Contains Windows 95 logo on what looks like a file or sheet of paper, including:

    1. Colorful logo
    2. Gray logo
    3. Colorful logo behind a transparent file/paper.
  - Also contains what looks like a black Windows 3 logo, but likely is something else, especially when considering subsequent icons.
- Windows 95 in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\INETRES.dll

  - Contains Windows 95 logo on what looks like a file or sheet of paper
- Windows 95 in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\softkbd.dll

  - The Windows 95 logo appears as a Bitmap image
- Windows 7 logo in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\sppcc.dll

  - Windows 7 logo with a blue curved arrow
- Windows 7 logo in Windows 7: C:\Windows\System32\spwizimg.dll

  - Windows 7 logo with "Windows 7"; Bitmap image
  - Windows 7 logo; Bitmap image

Comment: Could you include which "IMAGE" item it is in the explorer.exe (they go up to 797) for Windows 10?